# Find a counter sign

Tags: wordplay, lateral-thinking

Answer is a legitimate word, phrase, or number.

We've a list of contacts for a number of enemy missions. Can you figure out the appropriate countersigns to trick them into trusting you?

Operation Northern Groove:

Sign: I'm too hot 
Countersign: (1)

Operation Greetings:

Sign: There's such a difference between us 
Countersign: (4)

Operation Release:

Sign: I don't care what they're going to say 
Countersign: (10)

Operation Acquire Fortune:

Sign: What keeps the planet spinning (uh) 
Countersign: (6)

Operation Consignment:

Sign: I'm gonna pop some tags 
Countersign: (13)

Operation Brush Off:

Sign: I never miss a beat 
Countersign: (7)

Operation Celestial Steps:

Sign: In a tree by the brook 
Countersign: (4)

Operation Avian Liberty:

Sign: If I leave here tomorrow 
Countersign: (8)

Operation Edge Of Your Seat:

Sign: Darkness falls across the land 
Countersign: (4)

Operation Unconventional Euphoria:

Sign: Is this the real life 
Countersign: (15)

Operation Assemble:

Sign: He got joo joo eyeballs 
Countersign: (4)

Answer (score 5):

**Partial Answer**

> Operations are song titles and signs are lyrics
>
> Uptown Funk
> Hello
> Let It Go
> Get Lucky
> Thrift Shop
> Shake it Off
> Stairway to Heaven
> Free Bird
> Thriller
> Bohemian Rhapsody
> Come Together
>
>  Tried fitting the next part of the song lyric or the artist but that doesn't seem to be it. Have at it.